# What is the meaning of en in the sentence

Tags: grammaire, sens, ordre-des-mots, en

The sentence "il en est de même de toute restriction A" is translated to "the same applies to any restriction A". But I am confused at the meaning *en*, and what is *en* mean exactly here?

Comment: Have you looked up all the ["en" tagged](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/en) questions already on the site  and hasn't any of those answered your question? Besides, "en" being here a pronoun, more context would be useful.

Comment: Please do not close the question too quickly. The suggested question is not good because it is written in French and an answer in English would be preferred

Comment: You can ask for the answer to be translated into English by adding a comment underneath the answer @jlliagre is pointing.  You can also ask any further queries you might have on this use of the pronoun *en* in your comment.

Comment: Linked answer translated. Feel free to comment here or there should you look for more explanations.

Comment: @jlliagre, so the meaning of "il en est de même de toute restriction A" is "it is the same as all restrictions of A", right?

Comment: @hermes You should provide more context but the translation you provided in the question sounds better.  The idea is: *Any restriction A follows the same rule/pattern/whatever was expressed before*.